# Can't find DSProSFUsername field for populated with DocuSign API Username in Salesforce org user

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, salesforce-service-cloud, docusignapextoolkit

I am trying to implement **Apex Toolkit** by following [this](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/how-to/apex-toolkit-install/) tutorial. But I am getting error **"dfsle.UnauthorizedException: DocuSign has not yet been configured for this account."**. I have googled it. I have found [this](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-to-enable-DocuSign-for-Salesforce-for-an-existing-DocuSign-user) solution. But on following this solution, I can't complete step 8 because of not finding **DSProSFUsername** field in saleforce user settings.
In Step 8: "Update the field labeled DSProSFUsername with the value from DocuSign API Username that you recovered earlier"

Comment: I have actually received the same error, have you happen to find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Salesforce->Setup->Users->Click on user profile->Click on quick access menu on the right you should be able to see the custom field under "User Custom Fields" at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

For dfsle, (DocuSign Apps Launcher) this field is DocuSign Username. 'DSProSFUsername' is the field for dsfs (Legacy DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce) please make sure when filling either of these fields the DS user id is used which is a 32 character alpha numeric code similar to: 0f5e52c7-324f-4761-b790-045cf65af92d and not the email address.